# Multiple borders (Div on a div with borders)

Tags: css, border

What I am trying to do:
http://gyazo.com/e1bd6baee9730b61655c43bf05a071f7.png

Problem:

The black border won't work on the right side.

Picture:

http://gyazo.com/34b53980f862700b7444f433382b8b2c

```
<body class="container">
    <div class="contentbody">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


.contentbody {
margin-top: 10;
border: solid 1px #000;

}

.content {
background: #232224;
width: 940px;
height: 500px;
border: solid 1px #373638;
}
```

What have I done wrong?
Considering if you use a border on a border, it should work as two borders..
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I see what the problem is...are you saying the interior border is not showing up on the right side?

Answer (score 0):

Use css3...

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zBqUU/3/)

```
<div id="box-shadow"></div>


#box-shadow {
    width: 200px; 
    height: 75px;
    background-color: orange;
    border: blue solid 1px;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
}
```

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lucak/

```
.contentbody {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
.content {
    background: #232224;
    border: solid 1px #373638;
    width: 940px;
    height: 500px;
}
```